# esp8288 nodemcu wps support

Tags: lua, esp8266, nodemcu, wps

For a project I need wps support in the nodemcu firmware. To enable that I have added wifi.wps.* commands in app/modules/wifi.c and I have added -lwps to the Makefile in app. All builds well, but after flashing the firmware I get problems in that the firmware reboots in a loop.

Commenting out the calls to libwps.a and only having the lua commands in place makes the problem disappear. Is there a know issue, why there is no wps support in nodemcu?

I have a clone of the nodemcu git repository and a docker build environment for building the firmware.

Arnulf

Answer (score 1):

Found the problem myself. There seems to be a limit of the firmware size of 512 KB. I removed some modules when building to stay under that limit and then all worked as expected :)

Answer (score 1):

Found out that if I use the ESPTOOL_FS environment variable of esptool.py to set the correct flash memory size, the firmware size can be greater than 512K and there are no problems starting the module.